# Function mapped to reduce function to concatenate vectors together

Tags: r, function, vector, iteration, concatenation

I'm trying to write a function that maps a function to reduce to concatenate a list of vectors together into 1 with the very first entry and the very last entry.

For example,

```
reduce(list(1:10, 11:20, 21:100), r_cat, .init = NULL)
```

should return a vector equal to

```
1:100
```

This is what I have so far.

```
r_cat = function(x, y) {
    out <- y[[1]]
    for(i in seq(2, length(y))) {
        out <- x(out, y[[i]])
    }
    out
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `unlist` already does it. `unlist(list(1:10, 11:20, 21:100))`

Comment: @JilberUrbina i tried unlist(x:y) in my r_cat and it didn't work..

Comment: @JilberUrbina i figured it out... c(unlist(x),unlist(y))

Answer (score 2):

No need to write a new function, `unlist` solves your problem:

```
List <- list(1:10, 11:20, 21:100)
unlist(List)
```

If you want to use `Reduce` from R base, then you can use `c`

```
Reduce("c", List)
```

You can also get the same result plugging `c` into `reduce` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(List, c)
```

Comment: i figured it out... c(unlist(x),unlist(y))